# ExtJS 7: How to differ loading of packages resources that can not be bundled

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs7

We have a Sencha ExtJS7 based classic application using a package that requires a lot of js files to loaded seperately (read can not be bundled). So we are loading them via `package.json` `js` config

```
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "${package.dir}/resources/ace-builds-master/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"
        },
        {
            "path": "${package.dir}/resources/ace-builds-master/src-min-noconflict/theme-monokai.js"
        },

        <snipped................>
```

So there are many files that are to be loaded seperately and should not be bundled into one

When production/testing build these files are loaded before app functions.

Is there a way to load these files either when a panel that requires them are added to screen or at defer them after app is loaded and starts working

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to do this, you can't bundle the javascript into your app; all bundled code will get loaded as part of the bootstrapping of the app.

Second, there are vanilla JS ways to load more scripting code, but the way to do it with ExtJS is [Ext.Loader#loadScript](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.Loader.html#method-loadScript)

Another way to do it, if these are ExtJS packages (and not arbitrary NPM packages) would be to declare the packages in the 'uses' section of the `app.json`, which would allow you to load them dynamically with [Ext.Package#load](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.Package.html#method-load)

Comment: These js are not being bundled but has to be loaded seperately. These scripts are part of a package

Comment: If they're not being bundled, then you've already managed the first part. The next part is using the Loader.

Comment: So I am talking about a locally bundled package that requires some resources that can not be bundled